# "Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')" error occurs at window.onload function

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

Why do I get an error in the case below?

```html
//example
<div>
  <a id="previousFirstButton"></a>
</div>
<script th:inline="javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
      pageButtonSetting();

      function pageButtonSetting() {
        let previousFirstHtml = 'test';
        let test = document.querySelector('#previousFirstButton');

        // log: null <-- why?
        console.log(test);

        //error occurs
        document.querySelector('#previousFirstButton').innerHTML = previousFirstHtml;
      }
    }
</script>
```

"Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')" error occurs last line.

I'm trying to process it with an if statement in javascript because there are a lot of redundant codes, but an error like the one above appears, but I don't know the cause of the error and how to solve it.

Comment: Your code works. However, you need to close the curly bracket of your `pageButtonSetting` function

Comment: code works with the little code you provided, there must be another issue in your project

Comment: Aha... okay I will take a closer look

Comment: give the other codes so we can help you